# Probability involving preferences

Tags: probability, permutations

This question is verbatim from an online assessment for a quant firm.

> $A$ and $B$ want to decide which restaurant to go to. They have 10 restaurants to choose from and they each have an order of preference which is unknown to the other person. Their preference orders are assumed to be independent of each other. Here is the decision process: $A$ will remove 5 restaurants from the list, after which $B$ will pick one restaurant from the remaining 5.
> What is the probability that the restaurant chosen by $B$ is not in the top 3 of either person's preferences ?

I'm quite puzzled by the wording. To me it is unclear how $A$ removes 5 restaurants: does he choose the 5 he prefers least, or does he choose at random ? Similarly, does $B$ choose the restaurant which ranks highest in his preferences ?
Since this assessment is fully online, there is no one to request clarification from.

Assume that $A$ and $B$ choose uniformly at random. Then $A$'s shortlist is irrelevant and we can consider equivalently that $B$ chooses $1$ restaurant among the $10$ uniformly. The probability that the restaurant is not in $A$'s top 3 and not in $B$'s top 3 is $(\frac 7{10})^2$

Assume that $A$ and $B$ choose rationally: $A$ discards the 5 restaurants he prefers least and $B$ then chooses the restaurant that he prefers best. In this case, the only randomness is in the preference orders, which we can model with random permutations $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$. Label the restaurants $1$ to $10$. Then $\sigma_A(1)$ is $A$'s top restaurant and $\sigma_A(10)$ is $A$'s least favorite. $B$'s decision is $$R:=\min[\sigma_B^{-1}(\sigma_A(1)), \ldots, \sigma_B^{-1}(\sigma_A(5))]$$
and we look for the probability $P([R>3] \cap [\sigma_A^{-1}(\sigma_B(R)) > 3])$ which looks hard to evaluate.

Do you agree with my interpretations of the problem statement ? Are my reasoning correct ? Can someone solve the case where $A$ and $B$ choose rationally ?

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300014/probability-of-two-sets-of-items-containing-common-subset-of-items) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483465/probability-that-neither-friend-watches-favourite-movie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\eqd{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
It seems more likely to me that your second interpretation is the correct one.

The permutations $\ \sigma_A\ $ and $\ \sigma_B\ $ being random and independent means that
$$
P\big(\sigma_A=\sigma_1,\sigma_B=\sigma_2\big)=\frac{1}{(10!)^2}
$$
for all $\ \sigma_1,\sigma_2\ $. Therefore,
\begin{align}
P\big(\sigma_B^{-1}\sigma_A=\sigma\big)&=\sum_{\sigma_1}P\big(\sigma_A=\sigma_1,\sigma_B=\sigma_1\sigma^{-1}\big)\\
&=\frac{1}{10!}\ ,
\end{align}
which means that $\ \sigma_B^{-1}\sigma_A\ $ is a random permutation. Therefore
\begin{align}
P\big([R>3]\,\cap&\,[\sigma_A^{-1}\sigma_B(R)>3]\big)\\
&=\frac{\left|\big\{\,\sigma\,\big|\ 3<\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i),\,3<\sigma^{-1}\big(\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big)\}\right|}{10!}\ .
\end{align}
Since $\ 10!=3,628,800\ $, it's quite feasible to determine the size of the set $\ S\eqd\big\{\,\sigma\,\big|\ 3<\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i),\,3<\sigma^{-1}\big(\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big)\}\ $ by brute force with a computer program or script. I got $\ |S|=120,960\ $, which gives
$$
P\big(\,[R>3]\,\cap\,[\sigma_A^{-1}\sigma_B(R)>3]\,\big)=\frac{120960}{3628800}=\frac{1}{30}\ 
.
$$
It's also possible, however, to determine the size if $\ S\ $ by hand.  Note that

- $ 3<\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\Leftrightarrow\{1,2,3\}\cap\sigma\big(\{1,2,3,4,5\}\big)=\varnothing\\
  \hspace{6em}\Leftrightarrow\{1,2,3\}\subseteq\sigma\big(\{6,7,8,9,10\}\big)\ ,\text{ and}
  $
- $ 3<\sigma^{-1}\big(\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big)= \sigma^{-1}\big(\sigma\big(\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big)\big)\\
        \hspace{8.5em}=\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\ .$

Since $\ \arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\ $ must be one of the integers between $\ 1\ $ and $\ 5\ $ (inclusive), it follows from the second of the above relations that for $\ \sigma\in S\ $$\ \arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\ $ must be either $\ 4\ $ or $\ 5\ $, and from the first that $\ \sigma(j)>\sigma\big(\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big)=\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\ge4\ $ for $\ j\in$$\,\{1,2,3\}
\,\cup$$\,\big(\{4,5\}\setminus\big\{\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\big\}\big)\ $. Hence, $\ 4\le\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\le6\ $, because there are at least four distinct integers between $\ 5\ $ and $\ 10\ $ (inclusive) which must be larger than $\ \min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)\ $. Thus,
$$
S=\bigcup_{j=4}^5\bigcup_{k=4}^6\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=j,\sigma(j)=k\big\}\ ,
$$
and, since the sets comprising this union are pairwise disjoint,
$$
|S|=\sum_{j=4}^5\sum_{k=4}^6\left|\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=j,\sigma(j)=k\big\}\right|\ .
$$
Now if $\ \sigma\in\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=4,\sigma(4)=k\big\}\ $, then there are $\ (10-k)(9-k)(8-k)(7-k)\ $ ways in which the values of $\ \sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3),\sigma(5)\ $ can be assigned to the integers $\ k+1,$$\,k+2,$$\,\dots,$$\,10\ $, and, for each of those, there are $\ 5!\ $ ways in which the values of $\ \sigma(6),\sigma(7),\sigma(8),\sigma(9),$$\,\sigma(10)\ $ can be assigned to the remaining 5 integers in $\ \{1,2,\dots,10\}\setminus\sigma\big(\{1,2,3,4,5\}\big) \ $. Therefore,
$$
\left|\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=4,\sigma(4)=k\big\}\right|=5!\prod_{\ell=7}^{10}(\ell-k)\ .
$$
Exactly the same argument shows that
$$
\left|\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=5,\sigma(5)=k\big\}\right|=5!\prod_{\ell=7}^{10}(\ell-k)
$$
also, from which it follows that
\begin{align}
|S|&=2\sum_{k=4}^6\left|\big\{\sigma\in S\,\big|\arg\min_\limits{1\le i\le5}\sigma(i)=4,\sigma(4)=k\big\}\right|\\
&=2\cdot5!\sum_{k=4}^6\prod_{\ell=7}^{10}(\ell-k)\\
&=120960\ ,
\end{align}
as before.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer !